# Read multiple .txt files at once with console command

Tags: c#, command-line-arguments

Hi I'm programing a console application that reads in the text of a .txt file and then calculates the Flesch Score (how easy a text is to read). It's already able to get started by the console by typing in the path and some parameters f.e. `-f` "filename" or `-e` for english. Now I want to read in multiple textfiles with the command `-f "testfile*.txt`. The * means that it doesn't matter what is written after f.e. enumeration. How can I achieve that with a console command? Correct me if I'm wrong with something I'm kind of new to programing :)

Here's how I am doing it:

```
string[] parameters = new string[] { "-f", "-e", "-g" };

Flesch_Reading_Ease.FleschScore.Language lang = FleschScore.Language.Undefined;
string filename = "";
        foreach (string arg in args)
        {
            switch (arg.Trim().ToLower())
            {
                case "-e":
                    lang = Flesch_Reading_Ease.FleschScore.Language.English;
                    break;

                case "-g":
                    lang = Flesch_Reading_Ease.FleschScore.Language.German;
                    break;

                case "-f":
                    break;

                default:
                    {                            
                        if (File.Exists(arg))
                            filename = arg;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: [Read this to get started.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413233%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), especially the sample code at the end.

Answer (score 3):

If you use the [`Directory.GetFiles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getfiles.aspx) method it will return a list of files that match the wildcard:

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(folder, arg);
```

where `folder` is the name of the directory you're looking in. You'll either have to assume the current folder "." or split the path from the input arguments.

You can then loop over this list:

```
foreach (var file in files)
{
    // Do your processing
}
```

Comment: So when I just use `string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\myFiles", "*.txt", SearchOption.AllDirectories);` where in my code should I implement the foreach loop?

Comment: @user5462581 where ever you are processing `filename` now.